# Escape string to be passed as regex

Tags: regex, scala

I would like to create a function that creates regex matching an arbitrary string given at the input. For example, when I feed it with `123$` it should match literally `"123$"` and not `123` *at the end of the string*.

```
def convert( xs: String ) = (xs map ( x => "\\"+x)).mkString                 

val text = """ 123 \d+ 567 """                                                
val x = """\d+"""                                                            
val p1 = x.r                                                                 
val p2 = convert(x).r                                                        

println( p1.toString )                                                       
  \d+ // regex to match number                                               

println( ( p1 findAllIn text ).toList )                                      
  List(123, 567) // ok, numbers are matched                                  

println( p2.toString )                                                       
  \\\d\+ // regex to match "backshash d plus"                                

println( ( p2 findAllIn text ).toList )                                      
  List() // nothing matched :(
```

So the last `findAllIn` should find `\d+` in text, but it doesn't. What's wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to generate a regex within your script? I'm unsure of the question. In Java you need to escape \ with another \ e.g. match whitespace \\s. Unsure of the scala language.

Comment: How should it find ``\d+`` (syntactically) in ``text`` when the latter doesn't contain a ``+``?

Comment: @mhs: ups, typo. But it still does not work.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use Java's Pattern class to escape strings as regular expressions. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29

For example:

```
scala> Pattern.quote("123$").r.findFirstIn("123$")
res3: Option[String] = Some(123$)
```

Comment: Thanks! works. `def quote( x: String ) = """\Q""" + x + """\E"""`

Comment: In `scala.util.matching` there is also `Regex.quote` to do the same thing.

Answer (score 10):

Just to bring more attention to Harold L's comment above, if you want to do this with a Scala library you can use:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex
Regex.quote("123$").r.findFirstIn("123$")
```