# Scala: concatenating a string in a regex pattern string causing issue

Tags: regex, scala

If I am doing this it is working fine:

```
val string = "somestring;userid=someidT;otherstuffs"

var pattern = """[;?&]userid=([^;&]+)?(;|&|$)""".r

val result = pattern.findFirstMatchIn(string).get;
```

But I am getting an error when I am doing this

```
val string = "somestring;userid=someidT;otherstuffs"

val id_name = "userid"

var pattern = """[;?&]""" + id_name + """=([^;&]+)?(;|&|$)""".r

val result = pattern.findFirstMatchIn(string).get;
```

This is the error:

> error: value findFirstMatchIn is not a member of String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use an interpolated string literal and use a bit simpler regex:

```
val string = "somestring;userid=someidT;otherstuffs"
val id_name = "userid"
var pattern = s"[;?&]${id_name}=([^;&]*)".r
val result = pattern.findFirstMatchIn(string).get.group(1)
println(result)
// => someidT
```

See the [Scala demo](http://ideone.com/HD6Pff).

The `[;?&]$id_name=([^;&]*)` pattern finds `;`, `?` or `&` and then `userId` (since `${id_name}` is interpolated) and then `=` is matched and then any 0+ chars other than `;` and `&` are captured into Group 1 that is returned.

NOTE: if you want to use a `$` as an end of string anchor in the interpolated string literal use `$$`.

Also, remember to `Regex.quote("pattern")` if the variable may contain special regex operators like `(`, `)`, `[`, etc. See [Scala: regex, escape string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774306/scala-regex-escape-string).

Comment: I believe he requires `([;&]|$)` at the end as well.

Comment: Then it should be `([;&]|$$)` in the interpolated string literal. I believe it does not matter here.

Comment: That looks required to me, how doesn't it matter?

Answer (score 2):

Add parenthesis around the string so that regex is made after the string has been constructed instead of the other way around:

```
var pattern = ("[;?&]" + id_name + "=([^;&]+)?(;|&|$)").r
// pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = [;?&]userid=([^;&]+)?(;|&|$)

val result = pattern.findFirstMatchIn(string).get;
// result: scala.util.matching.Regex.Match = ;userid=someidT;
```