# Split a multi-line string when a line matches a substring in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

Split a multi-line string when a line matches a substring in Scala. Below is the same snippet code. But I would like to use proper regex.

```
val s1 =
  """
    |Hello;
    |------------------------------
    |GO
    |World
    |go
    |True
    |            GO
    |,I am Naga
    |+++++++++++++++++++++++++
    |GOTO School
    |GO Heaven
  """
s1.split("\n(?i)GO\n")
```

Output:

```
Hello;
------------------------------
World
True
,I am Naga
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
GOTO School 
GO Heaven
```

want to check using ^ and $ in regex instead of \n

Comment: Try `s1.split("(?mi)^GO$[\r\n]*")`. However, your lines seem to start with space(s) and `|`, right?

Comment: Works like a charm. How to ignore preceding white spaces.

Comment: What do you mean by preceding whitespaces? Like in [`s1.split("(?mi)^\\s*\\|GO$[\r\n]*")`](http://ideone.com/pyHdO8)?

Comment: I am sorry, I can't understand what your input is. If there are no `|`, then you need `s1.split("(?mi)^\\s*GO$[\r\n]*")`

Comment: Just edited the question, you see there is line "              GO" which should be removed as well

Comment: Could you explain: are there `|` in your string, or did you add it for formatting purposes? If the first one works for you, these are for formatting only. And you may use `s1.split("(?mi)^\\s*GO$[\r\n]*")`

Comment: Did you intend to actually include the `|` in your string, or did you forget to call `stripMargin`?

Comment: And what about `++++` and `----` lines? Are they there, too?

Comment: And do you need to split out `GOTO School` and `GO Heaven` as separate items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
val key = "GO"
val res = s1.stripMargin('|').split(s"(?mi)^\\s*${key}\\s*$$[\r\n]*")
```

See the [Scala demo](http://ideone.com/QAMUgz)

The regex split is applied after `stripMargin('|')` is used to remove the indentation first.

**Pattern matches**:

- `(?mi)` - the whole pattern is case insensitive as `i` is the case insensitive modifier and `m` makes `^` and `$` match start / end of a *line* rather than a string
- `^` - the beginning of a line
- `\\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `${key}`  - the value of `key` (note you [might need `Pattern.quote` to escape any special chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774306/scala-regex-escape-string) in that variable)
- `\\s*` - trailing line whitespace
- `$$` - it is in fact a single literal `$` - end of a line (it is doubled as the string literal is an interpolated one where `$` is used to introduce code)
- `[\r\n]*` - zero or more CR or/and LF line break chars.

Answer (score 0):

```
s1.split( "(?m)^(\\s*(?i)%s)\\s*$[\r\n]*".format("GO"))
```

Above the final ans.

Comment: The output doesn't match your requested output.

Comment: So you use my suggestion and posted it as your answer? You could inform me that it works as intended and I could provide an answer with explanation , not just "oh look it works" answer that won't really help others.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry mate, I will do as you mentioned. You are awesome.